# createIndex throwing error Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

Tags: liquibase

Liquibase is throwing :

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```

The sql it generates contains the schema prefixing the index name.
Postgres does not allow this.

```
        - createIndex:
            tableName: product_assets
            indexName: idx_product_assets_style_id
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: style_id
```

Offending SQL:

```
public.idx_product_assets_style_id
```

This happens with jre7 or 8, PG 9.3 or 9.4 Liquibase version 3.3.5, on Windows or Ubuntu.

The funny thing is other team mates do not see this.

Is there a setting somewhere to prevent this ?

Comment: Please post the full sql statement

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not specifying the schemaName in the changeSet, you must have a setting enabled in your environment that automatically includes the schema name such as defaultSchemaName.

I did create https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2460 which will fix the issue in Liquibase 3.4.1